# Installing Octave packages - command pkg not found

Tags: installation, octave, linux-mint

I've recently install Octave like MatLab alternative in Linux.

I want install fuzzy-logic-toolkit but the pkg command does not exist in my system

```
λ bgarcial [~/Downloads] → pkg install fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5.tar.gz
zsh: command not found: pkg

λ bgarcial [~/Downloads] →
```

How to can I use the `pkg` command?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/fuzzy-logic-toolkit/overview.html)? None of those functions you tried are valid functions of the toolbox. Or [MATLAB's](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/functionlist.html), for that matter.

Comment: @excaza Yes, I did read it, but is not clear for me how to start in the toolkit.

Comment: What do you mean "start the toolkit"? There's nothing to start in Octave.

Comment: Ok, I want says start to work with the fuzzy toolkit, in Matlab the toolbox is instanced with the fuzzy in the console. In Octave, I don't know, and the documentation just talks about of the functions that compose it.

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/fuzzy-logic-toolkit/overview.html read this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to run an Octave command inside your linux shell.

Aparently you are using Z Shell or zsh, pkg is a command inside octave.

Run octave first you should get something like this:

```
# octave
octave:1> pkg install fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.2.tar.gz
```

I havent use octave in a while so I might be wrong.

PS. You should run it as a root user
https://gist.github.com/gnomex/cd4bc898f7aa3f2ded58

Comment: @bgarcial  this is another question. Next time just create new question and select an answer if it solved your problem, dont modify your post, unless it explains further your problem.  What you are showing is a different problem than the original

Comment: Perfect Juan, I don't take into account that you say me. I will do.

Comment: This is the new question just in case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328230/using-fuzzy-logic-toolbox-on-octave Best Regards