# Using fuzzy logic toolbox on Octave

Tags: octave, toolkit, fuzzy-logic

I've install Octave and the fuzzy logic toolkit to work with Fuzzy Inference Systems.

```
pkg install fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5.tar.gz
    For information about changes from previous versions of the fuzzy-logic-toolkit package, run 'news fuzzy-logic-toolkit'.
>> pkg list
Package Name         | Version | Installation directory
---------------------+---------+-----------------------
fuzzy-logic-toolkit  |   0.4.5 | /home/bgarcial/octave/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5
```

But ... How to can I use the toolkit?

I type `pkg load fuzzy-logic-toolkit` and the command was accepted

```
>> pkg load fuzzy-logic-toolkit

>>
```

In this point I can test some samples and functions like in this [link](https://iemontiel.blogspot.com.co/2013/02/instalando-el-tookit-de-logica-difusa.html)

```
>> demo('sigmf')
sigmf example 1:
 x = 0:100;
 params = [0.3 40];
 y1 = sigmf(x, params);
 params = [0.2 40];
 y2 = sigmf(x, params);
 params = [0.1 40];
 y3 = sigmf(x, params);
 figure('NumberTitle', 'off', 'Name', 'sigmf demo');
 plot(x, y1, 'r;params = [0.3 40];', 'LineWidth', 2)
 hold on;
 plot(x, y2, 'b;params = [0.2 40];', 'LineWidth', 2)
 hold on;
 plot(x, y3, 'g;params = [0.1 40];', 'LineWidth', 2)
 ylim([-0.1 1.2]);
 xlabel('Crisp Input Value', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
 ylabel('Degree of Membership', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
 grid;

>>
```

And I can see this chart

[image]

My question is.

There is some way of use `fuzzy-logic-toolbox` in which I can enter the inputs, outputs, linguistic categories and ranges in the discourse universe, like `fuzzy` toolbox in Matlab?

Comment: `pkg load fuzzy-logic-toolkit` ?

Comment: I cant check this link because I am at work, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGWZSqrVAzo. It is even in spanish I hope this helps

Comment: @SardarUsama and  yes, this is the command to load the toolkit. Can you see my Update in the question please?

Comment: @SardarUsama How to can I create my FIS in Octave with the toolkit and not just use the functions? I want enter my inputs, and create all the necessary to build the Fuzzy Inference Systems

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes, in MatLab I 've install the fuzzy toolbox and with the fuzzy command I can see a graphical workspace which let me create my fuzzy inference system entering my inputs, my linguistic categories and my discourse universe and rules to view the system behavior and detail the surface graphics. In Octave I will should can do it too ...

Comment: If it's implemented in Octave, I would expect it to go by the same function name. If it's not already implemented, you would have to do that yourself. You can check how MATLAB implemented it by entering `edit fuzzy` in MATLAB command window

Comment: @SardarUsama I understand!  Although I think that in Octave will should can perform the same process using the toolkit like in Matlab

Comment: @bgarcial: Octave cannot do everything that MATLAB can. You cannot compare a relatively small community effort with the product of a company that has hundreds of engineers working on it for 30+ years.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, it seems you are expecting to  be able to open a graphical user interface just like you would in the Matlab Fuzzy Logic toolbox.  Something like what is shown in the Matlab documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/products/fuzzy-logic/features.html#building-a-fuzzy-inference-system).

From the [function list for Octave's fuzzy logic toolkit package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/fuzzy-logic-toolkit/overview.html), it does not appear that the package includes a graphical interface. The Matlab GUI does just call underlying toolbox functions, however. If you want to use Octave for this task, you will need to use the individual functions from the command line or a script.